# Shrink the size of a .png file

Tags: compression, png

There are many programs that claim to reduce the size of a `.png` file but none of the well known ones, `optipng` , `pngcrush` , `pngquant`, allow me to shrink to a specified size.    `pngcrush` tried its hardest, but the result was still way to big for my needs.  For `.jpg` files, `jpegoptim` has an -m option that does allow me to shrink to the size I need.   The obvious solution seemed to be to convert to `jpg`, shrink to the right size, then convert back, but that doesn't work either, the reconstituted `.png` file just jumps back to its original size.

Presumably, this has something to do with the structure of .png files.

Is there *any* way to get a small png file?    [This png file](https://are.berkeley.edu/~leo1730simon/personal/brownTerm_16icon.png) is an example of something i need to shrink to below 1K bytes.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: PNG is lossless, you just can't pretend to compress a PNG image to a pretedermined size.

Answer (score 2):

Use ImageMagick to reduce the colors, then pngcrush to get rid of ancillary chunks:

```
magick in.png -colors 8 temp.png
pngcrush -rem alla temp.png out.png
```

results in a 1621-byte file.  If you have an older version of ImageMagick, use "convert" instead of "magick".  Using "-colors 4" instead of "-colors 8" gets you a 1015-byte file, but the dithering looks very spotty.

Note that these preserve the transparency in the image, while converting to JPEG loses the transparency and makes the background a solid color.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution to your problem that I can think of is to use `.jpg` instead of `.png`. The `.jpg` format was mainly created for its high lossy compression but still gets a good enough image. On the other hand, `.png` is going for the full transparency and no quality loss. To sum it all up, `.jpg` is ideal for getting smaller files if quality doesn't matter, and `.png` is perfect for high-quality images that quality and colour really matter.

Sources:
http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/jpeg-vs-png-image-quality-or-bandwidth/5385/, http://www.interactivesearchmarketing.com/jpeg-png-proper-image-formatting/

Comment: Thanks to everybody for their comments.    My problem, unfortunately, is that I need a *really* small .png file for use as a button icon with fvwm.    For some inexplicable reason, fvwm won't accept .jpg images but requires tiny images!!!    It appears my only recourse is to try to encourage the fvwm people to allow jpg images.

Comment: @LeoSimon If you need to be below 1k, you're really on the borderline of having just a bunch of header info and maybe-extraneous data chunks blowing a lot of your budget. As everyone has said, PNG is not designed for this. That said, this image is fairly simple graphically and I suspect the image itself could easily be "redesigned for PNG" by using blocks of solid colors, no unneeded gradients, strict or no antialiasing, etc. I'm certain an image that was visually similar could get under 1k with PNG.

Answer (score 1):

I can get that 9.5 KB file down to 3.4 KB using the 8-bit palette PNG format. The image has a transparent boundary, which adds unnecessary pixels and an alpha channel for the whole image which isn't needed, since it's rectangular. After stripping the transparent boundary, eliminating the alpha channel, and using a palette, I can get it down to 3.2 KB.

To get any further, I have to use JPEG for lossy compression. At a very low image quality of 5 (out of 100), I can get it down to 1 KB. It shows some artifacts from the severe compression (look around the prompt > and _ to see some of those):

[image: icon]